# How to implement a table with round corners?

Tags: android, user-interface, border

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I have done:

[image]

The difference is there are some spaces between the lines and the border because I used `padding=10dp` for outer border:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#808080"/>
    <corners
            android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Am I doing this right? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the xml file as you want .

Remove Padding from your xml file and put padding in each widget. Here test.xml is your background xml file witout padding attribute.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Sample TextView"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Sample TextView"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

**Edit** test.xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#808080"/>
    <corners
            android:radius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding. Put elements in each box and add the padding to each of those.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
//remove the padding for the shape

**Solution 2:**
//keep the padding as it is

and put margin for your view i.e that line you are drawing as horizontal one

```
android:marginLeft="-10dp"
android:marginRight="-10dp"
```

//for the top one

```
android:marginTop="-10dp"
```